# Ankle tiredness

Tags: running, couchto5k

So I'm in the first week of c25k and just finished my second run/walk, but even in the first week I had to skip one of the running periods. My ankles and the front of my shins were so fatigued that my feet weren't lifting. What exactly can I do if I can't even do the first week of c25k? Should I just do the first week over until I can get all the running periods?

It's maybe important to note that I'm doing this concurrently with SL 5x5 which I've been doing for a long time.

I can't help but wonder if the lifting caused this. The first time I ran was after a day off, but today I ran after lifting just yesterday (squat 3 sets of 5 @ 250lb and DL 1 set of 5 @ 275lb). I don't remember my ankle being as tired last time.

I weigh 200 and an 5'9 with a bf% of around 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on the version you looked up, but the last time I did it, it [suggested repeating weeks that I had difficulty with](http://adventure.howstuffworks.com/outdoor-activities/running/training/couch-to-5k-running-plan2.htm). I had a few times where that was the case, sometimes because of general fatigue, sometimes because I hadn't gotten enough to eat that day, sometimes due to soreness. I also learned the hard way that having a beer before going running was a bad idea, at least for me. All of my "get up and go" tends to get up an go away when I do that.

Don't run if it's causing you pain, and pay attention if fatigue means your form is getting back (having your ankle flop because it's tired can lead to much worse injuries. I do recommend that, on days when you're not up for running, substitute walking over some varied terrain. It avoids skipped days where you do nothing, and it will help stretch out sore and tired muscles in a way that doesn't tend to put additional strain on them.

Additionally, the question of how to combine Stronglifts and C25k has been addressed in [How can I train for a 5K while strength training with StrongLifts 5x5 and minimizing detrimental effects on either?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/how-can-i-train-for-a-5k-while-strength-training-with-stronglifts-5x5-and-minimi?rq=1)